# MDriven: AccessGroups in Visible Expression ViewModel's column

Tags: mdriven

Can we use an AccessGroup name to make visible a column in a ViewModel?

For instance, if we have an AccessGroup called "IsLoggedIn" can we use it in Ocl to set Visible Expression for a column in a ViewModel?
What it would be the Ocl Expression to access the AccessGroup "IsLoggedIn" variable?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't read access group status from OCL. Try instead to put an derived "IsLoggedIn" attribute on SysSingleton with the OCL to signal logged in. Then, use that "IsLoggedIn" attribute in both the access group and your viewmodel column.

Comment: I added an derived "IsLoggedIn" attribute on SysSingleton and now can use in OCL: `SysSingleton.oclSingleton.isLoggedIn` in either the viewmodel and the access group. Thanks @Lars.